# RunningSum inside another

Tags: business-objects

I have a report with the following data

```
IdSource       20170629    20170628    20170626     20170625     20170624    20170623
Id1.           OK          KO          N/A          KO           OK          KO
```

I want to count the number of days my data (status of a workflow) is KO. `N/A` means the worflow is not expected, so it should not be counted.

Expected results :

```
IdSource       20170629    20170628    20170626     20170625    20170624     20170623
Id1.           OK          KO(2)          N/A          KO(1)          OK        KO(1)
```

The count must be reset at each OK.

In SQL, I would do

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when status = 'KO' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id, cume_ko order by date) as nbDayKO
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when status = 'OK' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by id order by date) as cume_ko
      from t
     ) t
```

I tried to use the `RunningSum` function without success:

- I need to inverse the sort on the date
- I cannot use the result of a `runningSum` inside another.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ugly and not very efficient, but I did not find any other solutions. Here is how I did it :

```
If ([status] = 0) Then 0
Else (

(If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);1) = 1) Then
    If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);2) = 1) Then
        If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);3) = 1) Then
            If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);4) = 1) Then
                If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);5) = 1) Then
                    If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);6) = 1) Then
                        If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);7) = 1) Then
                            If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);8) = 1) Then
                                If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);9) = 1) Then
                                    If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);10) = 1) Then
                                        If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);11) = 1) Then
                                            If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);12) = 1) Then
                                                If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);13) = 1) Then
                                                    If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);14) = 1) Then
                                                        If (RelativeValue([status];([dayOfWeek]);15) = 1) Then 15
                                                        Else 14
                                                    Else 13
                                                Else 12
                                            Else 11
                                        Else 10
                                    Else 9
                                Else 8
                            Else 7
                        Else 6
                    Else 5
                Else 4
            Else 3
        Else 2
    Else 1
Else 0)+[status])
```